# Why @client.command() doesn't work? Bot is online but !hello results nothing

Tags: python, discord, openai-api

Why @event.command() doesn't work when

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    
    if message.author.id == 1158491873392984114:
        return
    else: 
        if message.channel.id == 1158515911163121845:
                    
                    chat_log = []
                    chat_log.append({"role": "user", "content": message.content})
                    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
                        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
                        messages=chat_log
                    )

                    assistant_response = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
                    print("ChatGPT: ", assistant_response)
        
                    await message.reply(assistant_response)
```

Is in the code?

Full code:

```
import openai 
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands 

API_KEY = open("API_KEY.txt", "r").read()
DISCORD_TOKEN = open("DISCORD_TOKEN", "r").read()

openai.api_key = API_KEY

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hello')



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready!')
    print('------------------')



@client.event
async def on_message(message: discord.Message):
    
    if message.author.id == 1158491873392984114:
        return
    else: 
        if message.channel.id == 1158515911163121845:
                    
                    chat_log = []
                    chat_log.append({"role": "user", "content": message.content})
                    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
                        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
                        messages=chat_log
                    )

                    assistant_response = response['choices'][0]['message']['content']
                    print("ChatGPT: ", assistant_response)
        
                    await message.reply(assistant_response)
        



    






client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```